# Apache Kafka: How to receive latest message from Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am consuming and processing messages in the Kafka consumer application using Spark in Scala. Sometimes it takes little more time than usual to process messages from Kafka message queue. At that time I need to consume latest message, ignoring the earlier ones which have been published by the producer and yet to be consumed.

Here is my consumer code:

```
object KafkaSparkConsumer extends MessageProcessor {

def main(args: scala.Array[String]): Unit = {
  val properties = readProperties()

  val streamConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Kafka-Stream")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(streamConf, Seconds(1))

  val group_id = Random.alphanumeric.take(4).mkString("dfhSfv")
  val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list"         ->  properties.getProperty("broker_connection_str"), 
                      "zookeeper.connect"              ->  properties.getProperty("zookeeper_connection_str"), 
                      "group.id"                       ->  group_id, 
                      "auto.offset.reset"              ->  properties.getProperty("offset_reset"),
                      "zookeeper.session.timeout"      ->  properties.getProperty("zookeeper_timeout"))

  val msgStream = KafkaUtils.createStream[scala.Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](
                      ssc,
                      kafkaParams,
                      Map("moved_object" -> 1),
                      StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER
                      ).map(_._2)

  msgStream.foreachRDD { x =>  
    x.foreach {  
      msg => println("Message: "+msg)
      processMessage(msg)
    }    
  }                         
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
  }  
}
```

Is there any way to make sure the consumer always gets the most recent message in the consumer application? Or do I need to set any property in Kafka configuration to achieve the same?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find an acceptable answer?

Comment: I didn't, as per my comments for the existing answers below. Moreover, I lost track of it since it's long back I asked the question and moved on to a different task.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka consumer api include method

```
void seekToEnd(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

So, you can get assigned partitions from consumer and seek for all of them to the end. There is similar method to seekToBeginning.

Comment: I have posted my code in the question description. Can you please look at it and suggest me where to add this method? Thank you for answering :)

Comment: what value do you have for auto.offset.reset ?

Comment: It has been set to 'largest' which automatically reset the value to the largest offset.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage two KafkaConsumer APIs to get the very last message from a partition (assuming log compaction won't be an issue):

1. `public Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)`: This gives you the end offset of the given partitions. Note that the end offset is the offset of the next message to be delivered.
2. `public void seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)`: Run this for each partition and provide its end offset from above call minus 1 (assuming it's greater than 0).

Comment: I have posted my code in the question description. Can you please look at it and suggest me where to add this method? Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always generate a new (random) group id when connecting to Kafka - that way you will start consuming new messages when you connect.

Comment: I am generating random group id every time I start the execution of consumer application. It gets the latest message that way, but again if processing takes more time it keeps on working on old messages which I don't require.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set staringOffset to latest to consume latest messages.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("kafka-reading")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
 val df = spark
         .readStream
         .format("kafka")
         .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
         .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
         .option("subscribe", topicName)
         .load()
```

Comment: I have posted my code in the question description. Can you please look at it and suggest me where to add your code? Thank you for answering :)

Comment: You need to add this property when you are defining kafkaParams. consumer.forcefromstart=false   For more information you can see consumer properties. https://github.com/dibbhatt/kafka-spark-consumer

Comment: Okay Mahesh. I need a couple of days to check it out. I'll get back to you. Thank you again.

Comment: I tried it, Mahesh. Still, I'm getting all messages in sequence instead of only the latest message.

Comment: is value of this "auto.offset.reset"  -> "latest"?

Comment: Current value for that property is 'largest'. I'm using Kafka version 0.9. When I tried setting it to 'latest', I got run time exception 'invalid property value for auto.offset.reset. Please help.

Comment: You can refer the github of spark. Search auto you will find it. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/55b8cfe6e6a6759d65bf219ff570fd6154197ec4/docs/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.md Hope it will help you.